How to measure the ability to discriminate between two colors experimentally
CONTEXT
Species differ greatly in their vision ability in general, and in their ability to discriminate between colors in particular.
Humans' color vision is usually (some rare human individuals have less or, even more rarely, more types of cones than the norm)  based on three types of vision sensors, called ``cone cells'' (red, green and blue, making it trichromatic). Those three types of cone cells allow them to distinguish various colors depending on how much each cone is stimulated. The three pigments responsible for detecting light have been shown to vary in their exact chemical composition due to genetic mutation; different individuals will have cones with different color sensitivity.  Digital devices produced by and for humans are calibrated on such vision abilities: the reader is probably familiar with interfaces defining a color by its red, green and blue components.
Cats' and dogs' color vision is based on only two types of cone cells (green and blue, making it dichromatic, reacting to what humans perceive as blue and green, but mostly ignoring variations in the light frequencies perceived by humans as red: various shades of red will appear as different shades of gray. A red, pink, or orange toy lying in a green patch of grass may be difficult to see for a dog or cat. Similarly, a digital life enrichment application requiring to distinguish between two colors differing only in their shade of red (e.g. black and red, white and cyan, or blue and magenta) would be completely unusable by a cat or a dog, and most probably frustrating.
Many types of birds and fish have a fourth type of cone receptor to absorb ultraviolet light, making their vision tetrachromatic. Birds see in four classes of color -- blue, red, green and shorter wavelengths -- violet or ultraviolet (UV) – depending on the species.
A RIGOROUS PROTOCOL
Given a task and an interface previously known to be visible to the subjects,
an intuitive protocol to explore the limits of the visual abilities of OATH subjects consists in requesting them to perform the same task, but using an interface such that being unable to discriminate between colors makes it impossible to perform such task.
Such a protocol is rigorous but seems unnecessarily frustrating for the subjects.
A PLAYFUL PROTOCOL
Barbay et al. proposed in 2022 an alternate protocol to decide which pairs of colors can be discriminated by a given subject, displaying colorful balloons with colored marks mixed with plain balloons, rewarding the selection of marked balloons, and noting the pairs of colors of marked balloons which are less often selected, assuming that they are perceived as plain balloons.
Such protocol is less rigorous than the previous one (some balloons can be clicked by mistake, independently of whether they are marked or not) but seems potentially less frustrating for the subjects.
QUESTION
Which experimental protocols do biologists (and eventually ethologists) use in order to measure the ability to discriminate between two colors  of other animals than humans?

A good place to look would be the "Methods" sections of papers that use these sorts of experiments, such as this one on cichlids.

It also seems that researchers often look at the anatomy of the retina in addition to behavioral studies to study color vision in animals.

The methodology is going to depend on the specific research question; what are the visual abilities is not a sufficiently specific question.
